# how to fix "NameError: name 'context' is not defined"

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I want to use ajax in comments and reply sections of my blog application. In function based view everything is working fine, but I want to do it class based view.

```
***My function based view***
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post, reply=None).order_by('-id')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            reply_id = request.POST.get('comment_id')
            comment_qs = None
            if reply_id:
                comment_qs = Comment.objects.get(id=reply_id)

            comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post,
                                             user=request.user,
                                             content=content,
                                             reply=comment_qs)
            comment.save()

    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'title': 'blog',
        'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})

    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)

***My class based view***
class PostDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.object.id)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post, reply=None).order_by('-id')
        context['title'] = 'Blog Detail'
        context['comments'] = comments
        context['comment_form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #if request.user.is_authenticated():

        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            reply_id = request.POST.get('comment_id')
            comment_qs = None
            if reply_id:
                comment_qs = Comment.objects.get(id=reply_id)
            comment = Comment.objects.create(post=self.object,
                                             user=request.user,
                                             content=content,
                                             reply=comment_qs)
            comment.save()
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

        if request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context, request=request)
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk'], })
```

In my class based view in `if request.is_ajax():
                html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context,request=request)
                return JsonResponse({'form': html})` 
part it shows the error that context is not defined. So how to fix this problem or how to include it in function, since I have already context. 
There is no problem in my function based view code it is working as expected.

Comment: Try this: `context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)`. You can see this by tracing the source code of DetailView, you'll see that DetailView inheriting from BaseDetailView and you will found this script to get the context

Comment: Thanks Toan. It is working now. May be you would post your comment as an answer so I could accept as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because. You use context variable but it not defined yet.

```
if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Try this this get the context:

```
context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
```

You can see this by tracing the source code of DetailView, you'll see that DetailView inheriting from BaseDetailView and you will found this script to get the context

Hope this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

in this method:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        ...

        if request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context, request=request)
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

simple, you use context, but its not defined. Either pass it as parameter or define it somewhere as a variable

Comment: Hi Damian. how to pass it as parameter. I tried to make it global variable but it is not working

Comment: my context variable is defined in def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): function

Comment: @tepeholm that depends... what do you need the context for? is the context always the same? or someone is giving it to each function? is the same context for all the functions and all the class?